# Manifest#runtimeClass Understanding

Tags: scala

Given the following `Parent` and `Kid`:

```
scala> trait Parent[T]
defined trait Parent

scala> case class Kid(clazz: Class[_ <: Parent[_]])
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
defined class Kid
```

Now I'd like to do:

```
scala> class Foo[A <: Parent[_]](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) {
     |   Kid(m.runtimeClass)
     | }
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[_$1(in value <local Foo>)] where type _$1(in value <local Foo>)
 required: Class[_ <: Parent[_]]
         Kid(m.runtimeClass)
               ^
```

How can I get `Class[_ <: Parent[_]]` type from the Manifest?

Comment: I think you have to use `asInstanceOf`, there was a related discussion about it on scala internals recently https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/UlBrt6RLppc (basically why it's not typed)

Comment: could you please tell me the body of `class Foo[...]` per your comment?

Comment: I think that would be `Kid(m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you have to cast the instance obtained via `runtimeClass` to an actual instance of `Class`.

Example:

```
class Foo[A <: Parent[_]](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) { 
  Kid(m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]) 
}
```

or using `ClassTag`:

```
class Foo[A <: Parent[_] : reflect.ClassTag] { 
  Kid(reflect.classTag[A].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]) 
}
```

I think there was a similar topic, discussed recently on Scala internals. Related in a way that a question was [Why does the method runtimeClass of ClassTag return a wildcard class?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/UlBrt6RLppc).

Comment: If `Foo` had a single argument of type `A`, would it be safer to do:

`class Foo[A <: Parent[_]](x: A)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) { 
  Kid(x.getClass)
}`? Or, is it completely safe to use `asInstanceOf` here?

Comment: @KevinMeredith to be honest, I'm not 100 sure, I would guess so, I have never had problems with it, nor now when I looked had I found anything on that matter. If I'm wrong, I would love to be corrected. (btw. if you use `.getClass` you don't need an implicit parameter - just a side note)